# turn all <sup> into links with the link being the contents of the sup tag

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I have a text doc with superscript tags that I want to turn into links.

```
<sup>3</sup>
<sup>4</sup>
```

into

```
<a href="#3"><sup>3</sup></a>
<a href="#4"><sup>4</sup></a>
```

I can search for the contents of the sup tags using regex

```
<sup>*</sup>
```

But is there any way to replicate the contents of the tag, and replace it multiple times? Something like -

```
<a href="#VAR"><sup>VAR</sup></a>
```

Its probably a lot easier in JavaScript, but I want to hard code it over many files, using notepad++ or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find:`<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>`

Replace:`<a href="#$1"><sup>$1</sup></a>` or `<a href="#\1"><sup>\1</sup></a>`

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/16

Answer (score 2):

How about:

Find what: `(<sup>(.*?)<\/sup>)`
Replace with: `<a href="#$2">$1</a>`