# How do I add Wikipedia style references in my ReactJS application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to create superscript tags, which if clicked upon, redirect the user to the references, like in Wikipedia.

Now, I created the superscript tag and tried setting `href` attribute to it, but nothing happens when I click, even though the inspect element shows that the `href` attribute has been properly applied to `sup` tag.

This is what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let sup = document.querySelectorAll("sup");

    if(sup && sup.length > 0 ) {

    sup[0].setAttribute("href", 'https://www.google.com');
    console.log(sup, "sup")
    
    }
  }, [articles])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sup` element doesn't have `href` attribute, and can't navigate too.

You need to inject inside an anchor tag with `href` of the link you need to navigate to.

```js
let sup = document.querySelectorAll("sup");

if (sup && sup.length > 0) {
  sup[0].innerHTML = `<a href="https://www.google.com">${sup[0].innerHTML}</a>`
}
```

```html
link<sup>1</sup>
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be adding `href` to the `sup` tag, which won't work. Will only work on `a` tag.

Also, unless I'm missing something, you are overcomplicating things by using JS to create the link / tag. You can simply put the link inside the a tag in your HTML:

```
lorem ipsum <sup><a href="https://example.com">link</a></sup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The sup tags are dynamically coming from widgets from a CMS. So, I have to manipulate them in my JS code.

Comment: Ah ok. Well still, you need to add the `href` to an `a` tag, not a sup tag. So you could create the a tag in your JS code too and insert into the sup tags. You could use the existing text within the `sup` tag to now be the text inside the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The main important thing you need to change in your code is wrap your `<sup>` tag in an `<a>` tag, so then you can add a `href` attribute to `<a>` tag and then on user click you can successfully let user go through the link you will provide.

For example:

```
    useEffect(() => {
       ...
       const anchorEl = document.createElement("a");
       anchorEl.setAttribute("href", 'https://www.google.com');

       const supEl = sup[0]         
       anchorEl.appendChild(supEl);
       
       supEl.parentNode.replaceChild(anchorEl, supEl);      
       // supEl.replaceWith(anchorEl) // it does the same as above line, but very old browsers may not support *replaceWith* method.
       ...
    },[articles])
```

Also here you can read about what can help you better understand about `<sup>` tags and why you should wrap them in a `<a>` tag:
[Turn all `<sup>` elements into links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497219/turn-all-sup-into-links-with-the-link-being-the-contents-of-the-sup-tag)

And the last thing I want to note that directly manipulating DOM elements through `useEffect` hook is not React considers in the first place as the way for doing such changes into a DOM, and React is well designed to update the DOM through JSX and Virtual DOM, when state or props of the component is changed, which is a React default behavior. So, you don't have to do much things when React already can do it for you easily, and if you organize your components, logic and your code at all properly, you can get the most out of React.